# Iterate dictionaries (associative array) with their order

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting, dictionary

I want to iterate my dictionary as they were set.

```
declare -A params=(
    [apple]=Apple
    [ball]=Ball
    [cat]=Cat
    [dog]=Dog
)

echo "${!params[@]}"
```

> Result: `dog cat apple ball`
> Expected Result: `apple ball cat dog`

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't without sorting the results. Associative arrays are not stored in any fixed order. You can keep 2 arrays, one indexed array holding the key, and then iterate the indexed array retrieving the value in the associative array via the key.

Comment: Associative array are unordered list, not sure if there is a language that print the output in order/sorted.

Comment: @Jetchisel : FYI, the current Ruby for instance (different to very early Ruby versions) guarantees associative Arrays (called "Hashes" there) to return the keys in insertion order when iterating.